# What are the possible scaling factors of scale-independent pixels in Android

Tags: android, text, pixel

The Android documentation says to use sp (scale-independent pixels) rather than dp (density-independent pixels) for text. And settings on many Android phones (often very much hidden) can change the scaling factor that changes the size of sp text.

But nowhere have I been able to find a general range of what these scaling factors should actually be. So, my question is this. **What are the ranges of scaling factors for sp text available on Android phones in the market? 0.5 to 2, more extreme?**

There are a couple places in my development career where I've wanted to have text that scales but which I could put in a text view I could always know the height of. There's sometimes cool things you can accomplish if you know the height of all your elements before Android's measurement pass. But these optimized features are impossible if you cannot predict the size of your textviews.

Comment: they are same as `dip`. Only difference is that `sip` is also scaled depending on the font size settings

Comment: I know. The question is what are the scaling factors of the font size settings available on the market.

Comment: I don't think that font size settings are available on the market. Please clarify.

Comment: Exactly, this information is not on the market. So I was wondering if anyone had done any testing or if any of the engineers responsible for scaling factors knew if there were any guidelines.

Comment: What do you mean by scaling factor? Can you explain?